# Lag in loading an activity showing images

Tags: android

PLEASE HELP!!!

Let me introduce my app first.
This app is image viewer.
The first activity is gridview.
 The second activity is fullscreen of image.
When the user tap the screen on the first activity, the second activity starts.
In the second Activity, for sliding image, I used viewpager and my custom adapter(extends PagerAdapter)

Then the issue:
When tap the screen on first activity, the black screen appears for about 0.5 second and the second activity start. I don't want to see that. 
I want to see the first image of sliding image instead of black screen but I can't do it myself. How can I achieve this. Or How can I avoid that black screen.

Please help me.
Below is onCreate() of second activity

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d("Activity", "Start");
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen_view);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String curDirPath = i.getStringExtra("currentpath");
    utils = new Utils(getApplicationContext(), curDirPath);
    adapter = new FullScreenImageAdapter(FullScreenViewActivity.this,
            utils.getFilePaths(), utils.audioFilePaths, utils.fileType, this);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            ...
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            ...
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            ...
        }
    });
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    Log.d("Activity", "end");
}
```

This is the calling part of second activity.

```
Intent i = new Intent(_activity, FullScreenViewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("currentpath", newfile.toString());
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
_activity.startActivity(i);
```

This is code of loading image using Picasso.

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(new File(_imagePaths.get(position))).into(imgDisplay);
```

Comment: can you post the code used to start the second activity?

Comment: Images are pretty large, right? Try to load them async using Picasso or UniversalImageLoader.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it able to load sdcard files by Picasso?Then how to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The delay is because the Activity is trying to load the image. Try to compress the image or use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) for faster loading.

Examples of picasso usage (from documentation) as requested in comment:

```
// Resources, assets, files, content providers are all supported as image sources.

Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.landing_screen).into(imageView1);
Picasso.with(context).load("file:///android_asset/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView2);
Picasso.with(context).load(new File(...)).into(imageView3);
```

Follow the picasso link above for complete documentation on features, setup and usage.

Comment: and the `onCreate()` method of your second activity. Probably you are doing something there causing the delay.

Comment: Is there any way to delay the first activity screen to prepare second activity  creating?

Comment: Just load the image in Activity1 with Picasso, (even when you dont want to use it there) before starting the Acticvity2. I think it will then be cached in Picasso and will show up quickly. Also compress the image and resize it if the file size is unnessarily too large.

Comment: Thank you for your help.